# Stored procedure error: "Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

So I'm new to creating SPs and right now I am trying to create an SP to insert values into my table Report below.

```
CREATE TABLE Report (
    ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    STAFF VARCHAR(1000)NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(1000)NOT NULL,
    LASTCHANGE DATE NOT NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertOrUpdate(
    @ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @STAFF VARCHAR(1000),
    @EMAIL VARCHAR(1000),
    @LASTCHANGE DATETIME
) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Report(ID, STAFF, EMAIL, LASTCHANGE)
        VALUES(@ID, @STAFF, @EMAIL, @LASTCHANGE)
END

EXEC spInsertOrUpdate NEWID, 'Evlyn Dawson', 'evdawson@gmail.com', GETDATE
```

Right After executing the SP I following error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure spInsertOrUpdate, Line 0 Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier

Can someone please help me out with this issue?

Comment: I always get this error whenever I add the parenthesis for either NEWID OR GETDATE:Incorrect syntax near ')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks For all your help.I finally found a proper way of doing this within the SP
and I got a proper understanding of SPs now.This is how I resolved the issue

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertOrUpdate(@STAFF VARCHAR(1000),@EMAIL VARCHAR(1000),@CARS VARCHAR(1000))

AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Report(ID,STAFF,EMAIL,CARS,LASTCHANGE)
VALUES(NEWID(),@STAFF,@EMAIL,@CARS,GETDATE())
END

EXEC spInsertOrUpdate 'Evlyn Dawson','evdawson@gmail.com','Ferrari'
```

Note that I have also a CARS column

Comment: I really didn't want to leave my table with default values of NEWID and GETDATE.What I wanted to do was to somehow give these features to my SP.Thanks to everyone's helpful answers I was able to get it done.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I would start by calling the functions correctly:

```
EXEC spInsertOrUpdate NEWID(), 'Evlyn Dawson', 'evdawson@gmail.com', GETDATE();
```

`NEWID()` and `GETDATE()` are functions, so you need parentheses after them.

However, I don't think the lack of parentheses would cause that particular error.  You would need to set variables first, and then use them for the `exec`.

EDIT:

A better approach is to set the ids and dates *automatically*:

```
CREATE TABLE Report (
    ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
    STAFF VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    LASTCHANGE DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
);

CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertOrUpdate (
    @STAFF VARCHAR(1000),
    @EMAIL VARCHAR(1000)
) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Report(STAFF, EMAIL)
        VALUES (@STAFF, @EMAIL)
END;

EXEC spInsertOrUpdate 'Evlyn Dawson', 'evdawson@gmail.com';
```

I would also discourage you from using unique identifiers as primary keys in the table.  They are rather inefficient, because they can lead to page fragmentation.  Use an `identity` column instead.

Comment: Is there an issue with my SP or with the way I'm calling it?Cause when I use normal INSERT query my table accepts these values and it works.Also the parenthesis give an error whenever I try to add them to my EXECUTION statement

Comment: Thanks a lot.This really helped

Answer (score 1):

This error message is a bit of a wild goose chase, the problem is that both `NEWID()` and `GETDATE()` are functions, so require parentheses. Unforunately, you cannot pass a function as a parameter to a stored procedure, so you would first need to assign the values to a variable:

```
DECLARE @ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID(),
        @Date DATE = GETDATE();

EXEC #spInsertOrUpdate @ID, 'Evlyn Dawson', 'evdawson@gmail.com', @Date;
```

As an aside, [a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column is a very poor choice for a clustering key](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/)

Answer (score 1):

So if your just calling your stored procedure with getdate and newid why dont you just add them as default on your table?

**Table**

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Report_ID]  DEFAULT (newid()),
    [STAFF] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL,
    [EMAIL] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL,
    [LASTCHANGE] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Report_LASTCHANGE]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Report__3214EC27D2D8BF72] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Procedure**

```
create PROCEDURE spInsertOrUpdate(

@STAFF VARCHAR(1000),
@EMAIL VARCHAR(1000)

) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Report(STAFF, EMAIL)
    VALUES(@STAFF, @EMAIL)
END
```

**Execute statement**

```
EXEC spInsertOrUpdate  'Evlyn Dawson', 'evdawson@gmail.com'
```

**Edit**
Please also note that your lastchanged column is of type DATE, however if you want date with timestamp you should use datetime